# how to get a continuous rolling mean in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Looking to get a continuous rolling mean of a dataframe.

df looks like this

```
index price

0      4
1      6
2      10
3      12
```

looking to get a continuous rolling of price

the goal is to have it look this a moving mean of all the prices.

```
index price  mean

0      4      4
1      6      5
2      10     6.67
3      12     8
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use expanding:

```
df['mean'] = df.price.expanding().mean()

df
index   price   mean
0       4       4.000000
1       6       5.000000
2       10      6.666667
3       12      8.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO: Hopefully people will soon remember you from prior SO posts, such as this one.

From your example, it seems that @Allen has given you code that produces the answer in your table. That said, this isn't exactly the same as a "rolling" mean. The `expanding()` function Allen uses is taking the mean of the first row divided by n (which is 1), then adding rows 1 and 2 and dividing by n (which is now 2), and so on, so that the last row is (4+6+10+12)/4 = 8.

This last number could be the answer if the window you want for the rolling mean is 4, since that would indicate that you want a mean of 4 observations. However, if you keep moving forward with a window size 4, and start including rows 5, 6, 7... then the answer from `expanding()` might differ from what you want. In effect, `expanding()` is recording the mean of the entire series (`price` in this case) as though it were receiving a new piece of data at each row. "Rolling", on the other hand, gives you a result from an aggregation of some window size.

Here's another option for doing rolling calculations: the `rolling()` method in a `pandas.dataframe`.

In your case, you would do:

```
df['rolling_mean'] = df.price.rolling(4).mean()

df
index   price   rolling_mean
0       4       nan
1       6       nan
2       10      nan
3       12      8.000000
```

Those `nan`s are a result of the windowing: until there are enough rows to calculate the mean, the result is `nan`. You could set a smaller window:

```
df['rolling_mean'] = df.price.rolling(2).mean()

df
index   price   rolling_mean
0       4       nan
1       6       5.000000
2       10      8.000000
3       12      11.00000
```

This shows the reduction in the `nan` entries as well as the rolling function: it 's only averaging within the size-two window you provided. That results in a different `df['rolling_mean']` value than when using `df.price.expanding()`.

Note: you can get rid of the `nan` by using `.rolling(2, min_periods = 1)`, which tells the function the minimum number of defined values within a window that have to be present to calculate a result.